Compile time check that only one instance of a class is instantiated in the same scope
I have a class from an external library. Only one instance may exist in the same scope. I can assert(instance_counter<=1) that no problem in a wrapper class.
But I want to be sure at compile time. Is there any way to do this? I think not, but maybe in c++23 or c++26?
UPDATE The code is such, that nobody would instantiate such a class in a nested scope introduced by a function call even though it would be possible in theory. Hence, nested scope is not a problem that a potential solution needs to tackle.
UPDATE2 A singleton would not work. I really need a constructor and destructor to be invoked to achieve some RAII operations.

Including nested scopes?  How about wrapping the class in a Meyer singleton?

Good question but no. I have updated my question to clarify.

So let me see if I understand, f instantiates object, calls g, g instantiates object, this is OK. But if f instantiates two objects this is not ok. Correct? What about recursion, if f instantiates object but calls itself recursively which instantiates another object, is that OK?

Just use a macro that defines it with a specific name, if the user repeats the macro he will get redefinition error

I guess I'm wondering when you say scope do you really mean stack frame?

@john, I mean stack frame yes. And no nested scopes, i.e. also no nested or recursive functions instantiating the offending object. See the clarifications in my question.

@Ahmed, you are correct, I can solve this problem with macros. But then, how do I enforce people using those macros? Its not possible unfortunately.

@PatrickFromberg Simply have the macros do a cryptographically strong operation on the current line number and file name and have the object verify the operation on the passed in plaintext.  (I'm joking)

Use some external tool to create rule to check that (as clang tooling).

@Jarod42, this is so far the only viable solution. Get the AST and check its content. That could even check the nested scopes. Maybe even better than template meta programming which is always at risk of making a code base unpenetrable.

I don't think there is or will be anything in the standard (as of c++26) allowing you to do that at compile time. Few options remain:

asserting on a global or tls counter, (at runtime, of course)
using an external tool
instrumenting the compiler and the linker

The former is trivial and efficient; the second depends on what you may use, and the latter is many orders of magnitude more difficult...
EDIT: What you are wanting to do is very similar to what clang/rtsan (recent in clang20) do, except they do it to enforce realtime/non-blocking call contexts. Indeed there are static checks (via clang/llvm annotations) which are complemented by a rt checks (librtsan, based on tls counters and RAII scope objects).
